# Can not use Labeled Tuple Elements in react ,eslint Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

i already upgrade the eslint parser version but no use

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.22.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.22.0",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
"typescript": "^4.2.3",
```

not using CRA,i wrote webpack config by myself

code is here

```
///test.tsx
import { useState } from 'react';
//Parsing error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefinedeslint
let x: [string, number];
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting the error?

Comment: sure, i have edited the question @ArjunNair

Comment: I had the same issue. As far as I remember the problem is in react-scripts.
Try to downgrade react-scripts. This is not the best advice but it should help